# Cannot Found installed VS Code after Snapcraft Install

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, linux-mint, snapcraft

Dear fellow programmers,

Today I just decided to move to VS Code from Sublime Editor and I have installed Visual studio through *snapcraft intall*, the instalation is done properly as you can see below.

[image]

[image]

But after that installation **I cannot found Visual Studio anywhere**, I tried to find it on menu, desktop and terminal as well but no luck the Visual Studio is not anywhere.

My question is How to open an Application (VSCode) that have been installed using snapcraft ?

Thank for the helps.

Comment: Can you find the `code` file in `/snap/bin` or `/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin`?

Comment: I don't have bin under /var/lib/snapd/snaps

Comment: I think I will using another way to install VS-Code, Snapchart seems make everything harder instead of making life easier.

Comment: If you're using zsh, there are some known environmental issues in some distros/versions. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/supporting-the-zsh/2264 for more information and a workaround suggestion.